# Subscribing to consumer in rxjava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java3

I replaced the action call to Consumer in my code but while subscribing it keeps asking me to cast it to observer

Below is the code

```
public void fetchSubscriptionPlans(String url, String apiKey, String authToken,
                                   final Consumer<List<ContentDatum>> subscriptionPlans) {
    appCMSSubscriptionPlanRest.getPlansById(url,authHeaders).enqueue(new Callback<List<ContentDatum>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ContentDatum>> call, Response<List<ContentDatum>> response) {
            try {

                Observable.just(response.body())
                        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())
                        .subscribe(subscriptionPlans);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Observable.just((List<ContentDatum>) null)
                        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())
                        .subscribe(subscriptionPlans);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ContentDatum>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

I get the error on `.subscribe(subscriptionPlans);`to cast it as `.subscribe((Observer<? super List<ContentDatum>>) subscriptionPlans);`

What should be correct way?

And on running the code I get the exception

```
cannot be cast to rx.Observer
```

Comment: What's the actual error you get? The suggestion to cast to `Observer` isn't the error - it's a suggestion to fix the error.

Comment: @dano I am getting exception cannot be cast to rx.Observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong import for Observable. Have to use this

```
io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that your consumer is of type : `io.reactivex.functions.Consumer`

Second, I think that your `response.body()` returns not a `List` of `ContentDatum`.

I've the same error when doing the following :

```java
Consumer<Integer> subscriptionPlans = list -> {};

Observable.just("Hello")
        .onErrorResumeNext((Throwable throwable) -> Observable.empty())
        .subscribe(subscriptionPlans);
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried with both type of Consumers io.reactivex.functions.Consumer; and io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer; doesn't work out. Also response.body() does returns the list of contentDatum

Comment: yes I didn't realise that you're using v3 of rxjava ... it seems that you found the solution